# How to render MathML using C#

Tags: c#, mathml

I am currently doing a project in C# that requires rendering MathML for the user. I can't seem to find anything on the topic that is useful. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call one of the rendering tools at [MathMLCentral](http://www.mathmlcentral.com/).  That would save a whole lot of trouble coding up a renderer yourself.  Google found a couple of MathML renderers, including a .NET one, but all cost >USD500.

Comment: Do you mean MathMLCentral has downloadable source or just a means of rendering MathML online? Because I'm not seeing any downloads

Answer (score 0):

if you can render in webview then you could use frameworks like http://www.mathjax.org/ Look into sample Windows 8 app.