# Equation visualization for WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, math, expression

I have a wpf project written in C# and I would like to visualize complicated math expressions.

Are there any tools / apis that I could use for this purpose (showing complex math expressions to the enduser)?

Comment: "visualize" in what sense? plot a graph/3d shape or nicely print expression itself similar to TeX or Word (check [MathML question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082557/how-to-render-mathml-using-c-sharp) for this).

Comment: My definition of a good tool might not be yours. As such, this question has no answer, and will generate only discussion.

Comment: I will edit the question to avoid closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this one:
https://launchpad.net/wpf-math

Comment: Looks great and fits the requirements.